# Angular JqueryUI datepicker directive model change

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

I have an Angular directive that wraps JqueryUI datepicker:

```
angular.module('uiControls').directive('datePicker', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var options = {
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                inline: true,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                    });
                }
            };

            elem.datepicker(options);
        }
    };
} ]);
```

And I use it like that:

```
<div date-picker ng-model="currentFilter.filter"></div>
```

My question is:

The datepicker is opened when the current date is selected by default, but the model on the scope is null. Only when the user really clicks a date, then the onSelect event is fired, and now the model has a value.
How can I initialize the model according to the selected date in the datepicker?
I tried to add a watch in the directive, and change the model from outside, but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Question was asked a while ago but it may help others:
Try using an isolated scope binding '='. :

```
restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        ngModel: '='
    }
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        var options = {
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            inline: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                scope.ngModel = dateText;
            }
        };

        elem.datepicker(options);
    }
```